# this is a pyqt5 code which was working fine in my old os (manjaro) now its not working in (ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, plugins, pyqt5

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

it is a tictactoe gui game,I was working this project on manjaro linux it was working fine, now that switched to ubuntu its thowing some error  and i am a begginer here, someone please guide me here, thanks in advance

Comment: I 'm not sure but once I had to install `C/C++` `Qt5` and copy this file to `PyQt5`. Or maybe I needed to install some extra module or install `PyQt5` with `apt` instead of `pip`. Now I use `PyQt6` and I don't have this problem. Linux Mint based on Ubuntu.

Comment: I checked `apt search pyqt5` and I have installed `python3-pyqt5` and `python3-pyqt5.sip                                          (runtime module for Python extensions using SIP)`

Comment: Thanks, but what about that plugin error i am new here and i dont want to face the same error in some other applications so can you please tell me more about it...

Comment: I can't say you anything more. I don't have problem with extensions after installing `PyQt6`. As for me problem can be because `PyQt` was created for one version of `Qt` - ie `5.12` - but installed extension was created for different version - i.e. `5.8`